# SQLite Syntax for Creating Table with Foreign Key

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm creating a table with foreign key references. I'm wondering about the required syntax. Mostly I've seen the following (from http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_basics):

```
CREATE TABLE artist(  
  artistid    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  
  artistname  TEXT  
);  
CREATE TABLE track(  
  trackid     INTEGER,   
  trackname   TEXT,  
  trackartist INTEGER,  
  FOREIGN KEY(trackartist) REFERENCES artist(artistid)  
);
```

However, from the same site (http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions) I see this:

```
CREATE TABLE artist(  
  artistid    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  
  artistname  TEXT  
);  
CREATE TABLE track(  
  trackid     INTEGER,  
  trackname   TEXT,   
  trackartist INTEGER REFERENCES artist(artistid) ON UPDATE CASCADE  
);
```

The latter syntax is a little more concise, but I want to know if the result is somehow different (aside from the `ON UPDATE CASCADE`, which of course has an effect; I only included it because I copied the code exactly from the referenced site, and because I don't know that the above syntax doesn't apply only when making such a specification). I am working in Android, in case that matters.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

See the [syntax diagrams](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html).

The first syntax is a *table constraint*, while the second syntax is a *column constraint*.
In these examples, they behave the same.

You would need a table constraint for a key over multiple columns (where you do not have a single column you could attach it to).

Answer (score 43):

This answer might not be related to yours but i thought it should be helpful for others who are working with android database.
**IN SQLite Foreign key constraints are disabled by default** (for backwards compatibility). You have to enable it explicitly using

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1
```

after you establishing your connection with the  database.
Here's the link to the official docs that explains it in more depth.
http://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html 
Please navigate to enabling foreign key support in the above link.

Comment: Hi War_Hero, I am getting foreign key as nulls.Can you please look at it.These are my 2 tables Table 1 - final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE = "create table if not exists scannerValuess (id integer,partName text null,cost text null,foreign key(id) references scannerUserValuess(userid))"; Table 2 - final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_USER = "create table if not exists scannerUserValuess (userid integer primary key autoincrement,name text not null,mobile text not null,address text not null,date text not null)"; Please help me ASAP.Thanks in Advance.